# How do I edit settings in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, editor, settings

When I access Preferences > Settings, I get two windows in vscode. The one on the left has settings listed and tee one on the right has a small number of settings listed. I can edit in the right windows but not in the left. Also, I am not presented with a search bar in the left or right panes.

I am at a loss for what to try. I expected to be able to edit and save changes to settings. In particular to allow more lines to be presented in the Terminal pane.

Additions:
This is what I get when I navigate File / Preferences / Settings.
[Partial Screen Shot: Result of File / Preferences / Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Akt.png)

ALso re: VSCode
Version: 1.87.0 (user setup)
Commit: 019f4d1419fbc8219a181fab7892ebccf7ee29a2
Date: 2024-02-27T23:41:44.469Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22635

Comment: screenshot please. also, what are the values of your `workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings` and `workbench.settings.useSplitJSON` settings?

Comment: Would it be possible to show your problem screen? Also [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) is a detailed document on vscode settings.

Comment: did you send a comment with a screenshot and then delete it? please edit the image into your question post.

Comment: "workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": true,

Answer (score 0):

When you access Preferences > Settings in VS Code, you should see only one "window" open up. The window has two panes. The left should be a list of commonly used setting categories, while the right pane is where you can view the actual settings and edit them.

There is a search bar above the two panes.

[Example of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOww8.png)

The setting you are likely looking for is ["Terminal>Integrated>Sticky Scroll: Max Line Count"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc3V7.png), which can be found under the "Features" category.